# Create image objects from password-protected urls in gwt

Tags: javascript, ajax, gwt

I want to present some images in my GWT application. These images are stored in a password protected url, external to my site in the general case. I can use the    `Image(java.lang.String url)` constructor, with the user name and the password inside the url. So I can call:

`Image img = new Image("http://user:pass@mydomain.com/image.png")`

But then the user name and the password will be visible to anyone that views the source code of the page. I want to establish an authenticated connection with that url, and then use the plain url in the constructor:

`Image img = new Image("http://mydomain.com/image.png")`

I don't want to ask the user for a username and password through a popup, because in the general case he will be different than the one to whom the images belong so he won't have the credentials. The owner of the images gives to me their url, username and password when he registers.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user does not have the credentials to view the images, then you will not be able to load them from your user's client.  There is no good way to provide the password for them without also letting them see the password.

You could refactor this by sending the image request to your own server.  Your own server could then send the request to the external server, password supplied, and pass the response back to your user.  This is an extra hop, but you can keep the password completely secret.

If you're asking your users for their passwords to another site, you need to be *extremely* careful with them.  In general, this sounds like a risky endeavor - you're exposing a lot of different ways to gain access to someone else's files.  The fewer of those you can create, the better.  If the external site supports some indirect authorization method like oauth, you should definitely prefer that over requesting the user's password.

Answer (score 0):

You need to popup a window to that domain, and have the user fill in their username and password. For all subsequent requests to the same domain, you should not get a new popup. One way to do this, would be to create a hidden iframe to mydomain.com. That should trigger the auth popup.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I can't use a popup because the viewer of the page does not have the username and pass. Sorry if the question was not clear. I have edited it.